# wdsmcast useage and deployment

Tags: windows-server-2008, multicast, wds

I'm trying to use WDS multicasting to deploy an image. For some reason I can't get it to connect. Anyone know any guides on how to do this because I followed and few and none are working.

I setup a multicast session from the WDS server.

Then i boot into Windows PE from the machine I want to pull the download from.
I have the utility wdsmcast on that cd and i run it. Put in all the information and it seems right, but i get Transfer Failed. I tried changing a few things, but it never seems to want to download. Not sure if I'm using it correctly or what.

Thanks

Comment: are the two hosts on the same subnet?  Which multicast groups are you using?

Comment: @rnxrx They are on the same subnet. The server with WDS is also the DHCP server, but when I get a chance, i'll have to check the group and i'll have to check DHCP as well.

Comment: Are you getting any error codes in the BDD.log file? Before you cancel out of the WinPE environment, press shift+F10 to bring up a command prompt and check the log files. Log file locations can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927521). Also, this [Getting Started](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771670(v=ws.10).aspx) document should help to verify your settings. Last, [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637994(v=ws.10).aspx) talks about the necessary router settings that need to be enabled.